# discord.js not getting a users tag on mention

Tags: discord.js

I have a ban command where you can either mention a user or use their id.

When mentioning the user in the embed it comes up with undefined has been banned! I want it to come up with user#0001 that was banned when mentioning the user or by banning them by their id.

**Current code:**

```js
const switchc = bot.emojis.cache.find((emoji) => emoji.name === "switchcancel");
const switche = bot.emojis.cache.find((emoji) => emoji.name === "switch");

if (!message.member.hasPermission(["BAN_MEMBERS", "ADMINISTRATOR"]))
    return message.channel.send(
        `${switchc} **You do not have the permissions to complete this command!**`
    );

let banMember =
    message.mentions.members.first() ||
    (await bot.users.fetch(args[0]).catch((err) => console.log(err)));
if (!banMember)
    return await message.channel.send(
        `${switchc} **Please supply a user to be banned!**`
    );

let reason = args.slice(1).join(" ");
if (!reason) reason = "No reason was provided!";

if (!message.guild.me.hasPermission(["BAN_MEMBERS", "ADMINISTRATOR"]))
    return message.channel.send(
        `${switchc} **I do not have permission to complete this command!**`
    );

message.guild.members
    .ban(banMember, { days: 1, reason: reason })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
const bEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setColor("RANDOM")
    .setDescription(`**${banMember.tag}** has been banned!`);

message.channel.send(bEmbed);
```

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured out my own issue. What I did was instead of using

```js
${banMember.tag}
```

I instead defined tag by doing

```js
let tag = banMember.tag || banMember.user.tag
```

The new code is as follows

```js
const switchc = bot.emojis.cache.find(emoji => emoji.name === "switchcancel");
      const switche = bot.emojis.cache.find(emoji => emoji.name === "switch");
      
if(!message.member.hasPermission(["BAN_MEMBERS", "ADMINISTRATOR"])) return message.channel.send(`${switchc} **You do not have the permissions to complete this command!**`)


let banMember = message.mentions.members.first() || await bot.users.fetch(args[0]).catch(err => console.log(err))
if(!banMember) return await message.channel.send(`${switchc} **Please supply a user to be banned!**`)

let tag = banMember.tag || banMember.user.tag
let reason = args.slice(1).join(" ")
if(!reason) reason = "No reason was provided!"

if (!message.guild.me.hasPermission(["BAN_MEMBERS", "ADMINISTRATOR"])) return message.channel.send(`${switchc} **I do not have permission to complete this command!**`)

  message.guild.members.ban(banMember, { days: 1 , reason: reason}).catch(err => console.log(err))
const bEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
.setColor("RANDOM")
.setDescription(`**${tag}** has been banned!`)

    message.channel.send(bEmbed)


}
}
```

This will allow for the users tag to show up when baning by ID or mention.

Answer (score 0):

As you do not need a member object, the simplest fix would be:

```
let banMember = message.mentions.users.first() || await bot.users.fetch(args[0]).catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Using users instead of members in the mention getter.